# How to parse float with 3 digits after comma?

Tags: javascript

I have float number

```
var distance = 3.643462215;
```

I want the result to be like this:

**my distance is 3 kilometers and 643 meters**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets assume that `distance` is for sure float - if it's string, do: `distance = parseFloat(distance)`

You can try with:

```
distance.toFixed(3);
```

which gives you `3.643`; You can split it to separated values with:

```
distance.toFixed(3).split('.');
```

It returns:

```
["3", "643"]
```

So get it run:

```
var distance = 3.643462215,
    parts    = distance.toFixed(3).split('.'),
    output   = 'my distance is ' + parts[0] + ' kilometers and ' + parts[1] + ' meters';
```

Output:

```
"my distance is 3 kilometers and 643 meters"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var distance = 3.643462215;

var reg = /(\d*)\.(\d{0,3})/; // using reg exp, because split won't work with float numbers

var res = reg.exec(distance);

console.log(res[1] + " Kilometers, " + res[2] + " Meters"); // 3 Kilometers, 643 Meters
```

In script I'm splitting number in two pieces with help of `RegExp` ( before `.` and after it ) and then manipulating with result which is stored in `res` variable

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuL8y/1/)</kbd>

Comment: To skip `substr` you can use following regex: `/(\d*)\.(\d{0,3})/`

Answer (score 2):

```
var distance = 3.643462215;

var n = Math.floor(distance); // KM part

var m = Math.round((distance-n) * 1000); // meter part
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(distance * 1000) / 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution i can suggest is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var distance = 3.643462215;
var strDistance = distance.toString();

var km = strDistance.substr(0, strDistance.indexOf('.'));
var mt = strDistance.substr(strDistance.indexOf('.')+1, 3);

alert("my distance is "+km+" kilometers and "+mt+" meters");
</script>
```

Comment: It is't not `simplest` solution !